# Is there any free OCaml to C translator?

Tags: c++, c, ocaml

So I have nice OCaml code (50000 lines). I want to port it to C.  So Is there any free OCaml to C translator?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I'm sure there are better ways to do whatever you're doing.

Comment: Oh... No there are no other ways... (by hand is one but let's skeep it) I need C code to compile it using some tool called Adobe Alchemy for Adobe Flash player... So I will get 10-200x speed loss but it steel will be faster than code compiled from pure ActionScript... Main Idea - make an application run inside web page even if it is slow in it...

Comment: This question was a long time ago, but since Adobe recently dropped Flash player support, I guess now the good direction for someone who would have the same issue as you had would be to try [js_of_ocaml](https://github.com/ocsigen/js_of_ocaml) or https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ocamlrun-wasm or https://github.com/sabine/ocaml-to-wasm-overview, and compile to JS or WASM instead.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This probably isn't what you want, but you can get the OCaml compiler to dump its runtime code in C:

```
ocamlc -output-obj -o foo.c foo.ml
```

What you get is basically a static dump of the bytecode. The result will look something like:

```
#include <caml/mlvalues.h>
CAMLextern void caml_startup_code(
           code_t code, asize_t code_size,
           char *data, asize_t data_size,
           char *section_table, asize_t section_table_size,
           char **argv);
static int caml_code[] = {
0x00000054, 0x000003df, 0x00000029, 0x0000002a, 0x00000001, 0x00000000, 
/* ... */
}

static char caml_data[] = {
132, 149, 166, 190, 0, 0, 3, 153, 0, 0, 0, 118, 
/* ... */
};

static char caml_sections[] = {
132, 149, 166, 190, 0, 0, 21, 203, 0, 0, 0, 117, 
/* ... */
};

/* ... */

void caml_startup(char ** argv)
{
    caml_startup_code(caml_code, sizeof(caml_code),
                      caml_data, sizeof(caml_data),
                      caml_sections, sizeof(caml_sections),
                      argv);
}
```

You can compile it with

```
gcc -L/usr/lib/ocaml foo.c -lcamlrun -lm -lncurses
```

For more information, see [the OCaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual032.html#s:embedded-code).

Comment: and you can compile this code using C compiler (gcc for ex)?

Comment: Sure, why not? Info added above.

Comment: Grate, but how now for example call functions from my OCaml library from C? (I know crapy way of calling OCaml library from C but in order to port it I need to be able not only to nest OCaml lib into C but be able to call its functions from C)

Comment: Calling OCaml functions from C can be done by registering entry points using OCaml's Callback module.
https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Callback.html

Answer (score 8):

There is an OCaml bytecode executable file to C source code compiler:
https://github.com/ocaml-bytes/ocamlcc

So, first compile your code to a bytecode executable then use
ocamlcc.

Answer (score 6):

The [OCamlJS](http://code.google.com/p/ocamljs/) project would be a good starting point.  It compiles OCaml to JavaScript; it should be possible to modify it to compile OCaml to ActionScript.  Compiling to C would probably be more work - no garbage collection of any kind - but not impossible, particularly if Adobe Alchemy provides APIs to meet some of those needs.

Answer (score 5):

If I had some OCaml code I wanted to run client-side "in the browser" (which seems to be your intent based on comments with the question), I have to say my first thought would be to do one of

- Use something like [OcamlJava](http://ocamljava.x9c.fr/) to
  compile OCaml to java bytecode and
  deploy that using Java web start or
  similar.
- Port to F# (Microsoft version of
  OCaml) running on .NET and use
  whatever MS provides to web-deploy
  that.

And maybe if I was really crazy:

- Port the OCaml interpreter (which I
  believe is implemented in 'C') to
  Flash using Alchemy and have it run
  the OCaml bytecode of my original (unported) code.

A two-stage OCaml-to-C, C-to-Flash doesn't really appeal though.