# Conversion of Ocaml file to C

Tags: c++, c, ocaml, translation

I wanna convert an Ocaml file with extension .ml, .mll, .mly into .c/.cpp file. Is there any way in which it can be done.

Comment: You mean like automatic translation?

Comment: Yes, it can be done. Either learn the source and target languages, or hire somebody who already knows them. Rewrite as appropriate. I don't know of an automated tool that will translate Ocaml to maintainable C or C++ though.

Comment: yes, I mean like automatic translation

Comment: There actually _might_ be a way using LLVM (but I haven't investigated): [LLVM can emit C files](http://fdiv.net/2012/11/16/llvm-generates-code-that-generates-code) as output. And there's a [LLVM OCaml frontend](https://github.com/bmeurer/ocaml). Good luck from here on ;-)

Comment: Well its not THAT crazy of a request... Haskell can be compiled to C code by ghc so it stands to reason that it is possible to  exist for ocaml. But Google is a better place to find this out than SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate: Is there any free OCaml to C translator? - http://stackoverflow.com/q/2638664/1243762

Comment: Just in case someone is curious: the LLVM OCaml frontend seems to be a long-dead project.